# Is there a way to fold all multi-line Ruby comments in Vim?

Tags: ruby, vim, comments, macvim

I'm working on a Ruby gem and I would love to be able to hide all the documentation comments in the file because they are more for people using the library than reading or writing the code. I see the value in having the comments, but when I'm working on the code they are visually distracting to me.

In MacVim I can manually fold lines of code by selecting them and clicking `Tools > Folding > Create Fold`, but is there a way to automatically hide all comments using some sort of shortcut?

For example, the following code:

```
  # Returns a 2D array for Rails select helper options.
  # Also used internally for Formtastic support
  #
  # ==== Example
  #  # Create an Enum with some elements
  #  class Priority < ClassyEnum::Base
  #  end
  #
  #  class Priority::Low < Priority; end
  #  class Priority::ReallyHigh < Priority; end
  #
  #  Priority.select_options # => [["Low", "low"], ["Really High", "really_high"]]
  def select_options
    map {|e| [e.text, e.to_s] }
  end
```

would be displayed as:

```
  def select_options
    map {|e| [e.text, e.to_s] }
  end
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem but you shouldn't use the menus: Vim has pretty good default mappings for creating/closing/opening/removing and toggling folds. `:h folds` will tell you everything about folding in Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [this method](http://www.rtfm-sarl.ch/articles/hide-comments.html):

```
:set fdm=expr
:set fde=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s#'?1:getline(prevnonblank(v:lnum))=~'^\\s#'?1:getline(nextnonblank(v:lnum))=~'^\\s*#'?1:0
```

The problem is that this method would become the only folding option so that's probably a little bit extreme.

Comment: I entered those in but nothing happened. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: I've tried it before posting my answer and I can say it works here: comments are folded with `zc`, unfolded with `zo` and toggled with `za`.

Comment: Pretty delayed, but this works great for me! I'm using `zM` to close all folds and `zR` to open them. Found those commands at http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442438-vim-tips-folding-fun

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would like to play with `vim`’s `foldmethod` setting. Sorry for slightly vague answer, but I have no MacVim here so you are supposed to adjust directories/filenames in my suggestion yourself.

First of all, try `:setlocal foldmethod=syntax` in command mode to enable folding within your current file only. If it works, you have all the prerequisites installed (namely, the `ruby.vim` syntax file.) Try to add `let ruby_fold=1` to your `.vimrc` file. The latter should enable folding over all ruby files (or, alternatively you may explicetely set folding to true for all filetypes supporting folding with `set foldmethod=syntax`.)

Now you are to find `ruby.vim` over your file system to tune it up. To give a hint, on Linux distros it’s located at `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/ruby.vim`. My syntax file enables folding for all the stuff which “may” be folded (e. g. functions, methods, etc.) Copy the original file to your `$HOME/.vim/syntax` directory and adjust it according to your needs. Navigate through it (by searching for `fold`, for instance) and remove `fold` keyword where you don’t want the folding is applied. The names in syntax file are self-explanatory, so you would not be in trouble here.

Restart vim and enjoy your folding. Hope that helps.